# 404 error on specific admin page

Tags: admin-panel, currency, magento2.3.5, data-migration, 404-page

This is my first question on the forum, so please bear with me :

Working on migrating a magento store using version 2.3.5 with imported data form a 1.9.3 magento store.

The problem I am having is that I cannot acces the admin page
**/admin/system_currency/**

it throws a 404 error like below :

[image: 404 erro]

I was able to see this a 404 error because I temporaryliy disabled adding the secret key to the admin url :

```
bin/magento config:set admin/security/use_form_key 0
```

Otherwise before it was showing up as just an invalid form key error.

I am still eearly in the Dev process however, it seems to me a tough all of the other admin menus are working fine. It's just this one menu. I am suspecting this might be related to the import perhaps missing a key in **core_config_data**. Can you helpp me troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: please check admin role . its assigned to your or note?

Comment: Role ressource is set to ALL in :
admin/user_role/editrole/

Comment: run once php bin/magento setup:upgrade and php bin/magento setup:di:compile

Comment: done but, no joy

Comment: @GohilRajesh : I went ahead and recreated a new admin role checking all ppossible permissions and when I assigned it to my user and upon re-login the currency menu doesn't even show on the  left panel.

Comment: Its default magento functionality..had u changed anything previously in that system.xml file??

Comment: no I haven't updated any xml files. 
Here is what i did so far.
1. imported the setings and and data with the data import tool.
2. installed porto theme
3. configured for multi-sites creating websites stores and store views and running them using mage MAGE_RUN_TYPE & MAGE_RUN_CODE 
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/multi-site/ms_nginx.html

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED : I actually realized that this functionality needed `Magento_CurrencySymbol` module to be enabled.
Enabled the module and all seems to work fine now. Hopefully this wil help someone else.